# Do not get the whole $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

When I click on the `submit` button it should give a `$_POST` to my send page.

What I do is:

-> When Click on `<input type="submit" name="sendMail" value="Verzend E-Mail" class="sendMail">`
-> I make a var `link` and set the whole `<form action="" method="post" id="formSendMail">` in it.
-> Then give with a `$.ajax()` request the `link` as data to the page where I send it to.
-> When `.done(function(data))` put data in `$("div.emailSendComplete")`

So now you know what I exually want...

What I have till now on code is:

```
Jquery:
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.sendMail").on("click", function(){
        var link = $("form#sendMailForm");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checklistHandler.php?action=sendMail",
            data: link
        }).done(function (data){
            $("div.emailSendComplete").append(data);
        });
    });
  });
</script>

HTML:
<table id="cont" style="line-height: 80px; text-align: center;">
<tr id="sendMail" style="">
    <form action="checklistHandler.php" method="post" id="sendMailForm">
        <td style="width: 150px;">Email:</td>
        <td>
            <input style="padding: 5px; text-align: center; min-width: 10px; border-radius: 3px;" id="email" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?= $email ?>">
            <span class="emailCheck"></span>
        </td>
        <td style="position: relative; left: 50px;">
            <input type="hidden" name="verzendMail" value="1">
            <input type="submit" name="sendMail" value="Verstuur E-Mail" class="sendMail" style="border-radius: 3px;">
        </td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

```
PHP(checklistHandler.php):
if ($_GET['action'] == 'sendMail') {
   print_r($_POST);
   exit();
}
```

Comment: I did not changed that. I updated IT!

Comment: @NarendraSisodia I tried several things and didn't changed that back ;)

Comment: inside checklistHandler.php change  if ($_GET['action'] == 'sendMail')  to if ($_POST['action'] == 'sendMail')

Comment: @mikeO. I don't have a `$_POST` name with action. Its that I give it in the link in the `$.ajax`  request

Comment: OP is using URL to send `?action`, so he needs to use $_GET there. He's sending the rest of his data via `type: "POST"` so needs to use $_POST there. He's fine.

Comment: @PeterBowers you are right my bad..

Comment: @Lenap You should not change the original code as it will invalidate the answers given. Just put the current version below the original question.

Comment: @jeroen srry I will do it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved:

The I did try to give the whole POST but I also could only give the INPUT with the email in it.
Cuz I only needed that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to send the HTML of the form? If so, instead of this:

```
var link = $("form#formSendMail");
```

(That will return a jquery object unless I'm mistaken)

use this:

```
var link = $("#formSendMail").html();
```

Not entirely clear what you are trying to do, so I may have misunderstood...

Comment: I need to get all the `<input>'s` of the `<form>` that is what I want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

There are <strike>two</strike> three problems here:

- You are not cancelling the default form submit, so your form will submit the normal way as well and your page will be refreshed;
- You are not sending any data to your script with your ajax call, just a jQuery object, the form;
- Your form has a different ID than the one you are using in your ajax call: `formSendMail` vs `sendMailForm`.

It should look more or less like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input.sendMail").on("click", function(event){
                                           ^^^^^ you need this later on

    // second and third problem, missing data and wrong ID
    var link = $("form#sendMailForm").serialize();
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^ use the right ID here

    // first problem, default submit
    event.preventDefault();

    // the rest of your code
```

Comment: Doesn't work by me. Its still only give `Array()`

Comment: @Lenap Yep, found a third problem, the ID of the form is different from the one in your ajax call...

Comment: good call, and I changed it but it didn't canged antything. It still gives `Array()`

Comment: @Lenap So check each step, first check if `link` contains the correct data. You should also post the corrected code and output below the original version.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to change in your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //instead of input button click use form
    $("#sendMailForm").submit(function(e){
        // first problem, prevent default submit
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = $('#sendMailForm').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checklistHandler.php?action=sendMail&email=",
            data: link
        }).done(function (data){
            $("div.emailSendComplete").append(data);
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: I dont get any response. I also add a `alert()` but that also didn't run!

Comment: Please check whether your "checklistHandler.php" file in the same folder.

Comment: Yes it is in the same folder. Im 100% sure.

Comment: Just try ,coment the js code and check whether your getting the post value in you php file.